# DriveApp.getFileById(fileId) feature disabled by admin

Tags: google-apps-script

I am try to use MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options), but DriveApp.getFileById(fileId); disable by domain admin, how to solve this problem?

Is it able to solve this problem without admin?

[DriveApp disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04hHU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Only the Google Apps domain administrator can enable the Google Drive service for your Google Account. This [page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6115117?hl=en) has instructions on how to turn on Drive for specific users.

Answer (score 0):

You might have access to Google drive but may be administrator of G Suit domains has disabled Drive SDK for the domain.  (this will prevent executing scripts)

**Note:** *Administrators of G Suite domains have the ability to disable the Drive SDK for their domain, which prevents their users from installing and using Google Drive apps. This setting will also prevent the users from being able to use Apps Script scripts, web apps and add-ons that use the Drive service or Advanced Drive Service (even the add-on or web app in question was installed prior to the admin disabling Drive SDK).*

*However, if an add-on (or web app) using the Drive service is published for domain-wide installation and is installed by the administrator for some or all users in the domain, the add-on will function for those users even if the Drive SDK is disabled in the domain.*

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/